# How to set min and max prices for products using Amazon MWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services, max, min, amazon-mws

Is it possible to set the minimum-seller-allowed-price and maximum-seller-allowed-price prices of products via flat file AND submit it as a feed via the MWS API?

Sellers will have to specify a min and max price for all items from 15th Jan 2015 onwards viz:

"With effect from January 14, 2015, you will not be able to use the Seller Central preferences to select a blanket “opt-out” from all potential low and high-pricing error rules. The aim is to reduce price error risks to sellers and avoid potentially negative buyer experiences. Instead, you will need to set a minimum and maximum allowed selling price for each product in your inventory. If you do not chose pricing limits for each product, Amazon’s default potential pricing error rules will apply to your products...."

So, from reading "https://sellercentral-europe.amazon.com/gp/help/201141430" this implies that it can be done via a "Price & Quantity Inventory" file.  However, the solution that I'm after needs to be done via the MWS API.

For normal price feeds, I'd set the feed type to _POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_ too.

I don't think that you can set the min and max prices via XML as the price feed XSD does not contain a definition for these fields (not that I can find anyway).

Sai.

Comment: Just got a reply back from Amazon.  The required fields are defined in the latest Price XSD and are called:  MinimumSellerAllowedPrice
MaximumSellerAllowedPrice both of which are of type StringOverrideCurrencyAmount.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a small sample if you need for type _POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_ feed on mws (here it's for amazon.co.uk):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>YOUR_ID</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
   <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
<Price>
    <SKU>YOUR_SKU</SKU>
    <StandardPrice currency="GBP">30.75</StandardPrice>
 <MinimumSellerAllowedPrice currency="GBP">20</MinimumSellerAllowedPrice>
    <MaximumSellerAllowedPrice currency="GBP">40</MaximumSellerAllowedPrice>
</Price>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: many thanks for this @chocobn69!    Word of warning: if there's a problem with this pricing data then the item on the marketplace is marked as a pricing error, and the only way to correct it is manually.   So if you change a gazillion prices wrongly.... :(

Comment: I don't know yet. I'm currently facing the same problem. I will tell you when I'll know

Comment: How does this work with decimal MinimumSellerAllowedPrice? `20.01` and `20,01` cause errors (Error code `5000`)

Answer (score 3):

Amazon provides [this schema](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/Price.xsd) for their Price feed.
The MinimumSellerAllowedPrice and MaximumSellerAllowedPrice fields can be used to specify the min and max prices and they would look like this :

```
<MinimumSellerAllowedPrice currency="GBP">12.3</MinimumSellerAllowedPrice>
<MaximumSellerAllowedPrice currency="GBP">23.4</MaximumSellerAllowedPrice>
```

Be aware that if the currency is "EUR" you will have to specify the values for these 2 fields using comma :

```
<MinimumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">11,1</MinimumSellerAllowedPrice>
```

Also note that the StandardPrice field should always be using dot for value representation, so 11.1 , even if the currency is "EUR".

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan, not sure how to respond to your comment but below is an example of XML data that I send to update the price (MinimumSellerAllowedPrice = 24.94).

```
<AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>ABC123</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Price>
            <SKU>13182</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="GBP">11.96</StandardPrice>
            <MinimumSellerAllowedPrice currency="GBP">11.1</MinimumSellerAllowedPrice>
            <MaximumSellerAllowedPrice currency="GBP">24.94</MaximumSellerAllowedPrice>
        </Price>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

And for me, Amazon processes these requests without error, and so if you're getting error code 5000 in the response, contact Amazon support and send them your XML together with the response.  They should get back to you with an answer.